# Ajax function stop loading screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a delete function that deletes an entry from a serverside datatable. The intention was when i select several items via checkbox and press delete, a loading screen would appear as my function is called. Once the amount of items are properly deleted, the loading should fade away.

However, at the moment the loading screen doesn't go away once all items are properly deleted. I'm hoping someone can see where I have gone wrong with this. Thank you

Ajax Code

```
function deleteDocumentPrepare(){
  var delCounter = 0;
  if(checked!==null){
        $('.loading').show();
       $.each(checked, function(key, value) {
//           console.log(checked.length);
            deleteDocument(value,delCounter,checked.length);
            delCounter++;
//            console.log(delCounter);
        });

    }
}

function deleteDocument(input,current,total){
//    console.log("current:"+current);
//    console.log("total:"+total);
    var id = input;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('/Common/Check'); ?>",
        success: function(data){
            if("<?php echo $this->data['controller'];?>"=="Support"){
                var url = '<?php echo site_url('Admin'.$this->data['controller'].'/Agent/Delete/'); ?>';
            }else{
                var url = '<?php echo site_url('Admin'.$this->data['controller'].'/Delete/'); ?>';
            }
            if(data==true){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:url,
                    data:'id='+id,
                    beforeSend: function () {
//                        $('.loading').show();
                    },
                    success:function(result){
                        if(current==total){
//                           console.log("END");
                           $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
                           checked=[];
                           table.draw();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                window.location.href="<?php echo site_url('/');?>";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where do you hide the loading screen?  Is that line of code reached?  If not, why not?  When you step through using the browser's debugger, where does the behavior differ from what you expect?

Comment: The loading screen is hidden once the ajax function is done. That is the expected action

Comment: And *when you debug*, where does it fail?

Comment: It fails at the if(current==total) line. It doesn't enter it even though the values match from the parameters

Comment: I think, you should send `current` and `total` in AJAX data, and send them again from the request. You will receive those values in `result` and post that you can do your checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears because of difference between element index and found elements length, so

```
if(current==total){}
```

this condition in your code will be always `false` because `lastIndex == length-1`. And in this case condition must be

```
if(current==total - 1){}
```

Comment: Ah yours works for me. I can't believe I overlooked something like that

Comment: I will mark it as correct when the 5 mins are up. Thank you!

Comment: Just a fresh sight on the thing :-)